# How to retry/resume broken downloads in Firefox WebExtension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, download-manager

I am looking for a way to retry/resume broken downloads in a WebExtension.   I know there is the downloads.resume() method, but that only works for paused downloads and not broken ones caused by network failures.  In the download manager, there is the retry button that can restart the broken download and resume where if left off.  How can I do this with the API?

Comment: It's not possible yet. Try filing a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ (product Toolkit, division WebExtensions)

Comment: I submitted the request here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1467059

Comment: Great. It would be a wonderful addition to the API.